# Having issues iterating a statement, C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Q1 {
  public class Q1 {
    static void Main() {
        // Keep the following line intact 
        Console.WriteLine("===========================");

        // Insert your solution here.

        const string EMPTY = "You have 0 eggs which equals 0 dozen and 0 eggs left over.";
        const string ZEROEGG = "You have 0 eggs which equals 0 dozen and 0 eggs left over.";
        const string NEGATIVEGG = "You have 0 eggs which equals 0 dozen and 0 eggs left over.";
        const string TWELVEEGG = "You have 12 eggs which equals 1 dozen and 0 eggs left over.";

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of chickens:");
        int chickens = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        {

          if (chickens <= 0) {

            Console.WriteLine(EMPTY);
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
            return;

          }

          Console.WriteLine("Eggs:");
          int egg_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

          if (chickens == 1)

          {

            switch (egg_) {
            case 0:
              Console.WriteLine(ZEROEGG);
              break;

            case <= -1:
              Console.WriteLine(NEGATIVEGG);
              break;

            case 1:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " egg which equals 0 dozen and " + egg_ + " egg left over.");
              break;

            case <= 11:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " eggs which equals 0 dozen and " + egg_ + " eggs left over.");
              break;

            case 12:
              Console.WriteLine(TWELVEEGG);
              break;

            case 13:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " eggs which equals 1 dozen and " + (egg_ - 12) + " egg left over.");
              break;

            case < 24:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " eggs which equals 1 dozen and " + (egg_ - 12) + " eggs left over.");
              break;

            case 24:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " eggs which equals 2 dozen and 0 eggs left over.");
              break;

            case > 24:
              Console.WriteLine("You have " + egg_ + " eggs which equals " + (egg_ / 12) + " dozen " + (egg_ - 12) + " eggs left over.");
              break;

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < chickens; ++i)

            {
              Console.Write("Eggs:");
              egg_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

          }
```

I want the code to prompt the user with the writeline statement equal to the number of chickens i.e. chickens = 4, Console.Write("Eggs:") 4 times.

Ive tried while loop and if statements but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What is the input you are providing?

Comment: What's `egg_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` for?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of chickens:");
                         int chickens = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: Your program is waiting for you to type something because of this line `egg_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` What are you typing to the program?

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @berserck no its just that it wont prompt the user with the console writeline statement as many times as there are chickens, if the user input is 2 chickens i want it to prompt the user with  Console.WriteLine("Eggs:"); 2 times

Comment: You really should read [ask] and then write your whole question out. So far what you've asked and the code you've posted has changed what the answer should be several times. And you've put detail in the comments rather than the question itself.

Comment: And this is why you want an IDE. I've autoformat your code and now it's obvious your whole logics are inside the `if (chickens == 1)`, so of course it won't execute for any other values

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger

Comment: @Martheen so how do i solve this and for the IDE i'm using vs code.

Comment: I feel like whatever the task you've been assigned is you've misinterpreted it. Might be a good idea to take a step back, read the task again carefully and break it down into small pseudocode steps, then write code to implement those steps.

Comment: VSCode also has https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging, but unless you're not in Windows, it's much easier to use the full VS, Community edition is free

Comment: it seems to me you have multiple bugs in you code:
1. you ask once for the number of eggs before the switch
2. the loop asking for eggs is inside the if condition for when chickens == 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've asked and said in the comments, this sounds like what you need:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Keep the following line intact 
    Console.WriteLine("===========================");

    // Insert your solution here.

    string Message(int eggs)
    {
        int dozen = eggs / 12;
        int left_over = eggs % 12;
        return $"You have {eggs} egg{(eggs == 1 ? "" : "s")} which equals {dozen} dozen and {left_over} egg{(left_over == 1 ? "" : "s")} left over.";

    }

    int chickens = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of chickens:");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out chickens))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of chickens:");
    }

    if (chickens <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Message(0));
        Console.WriteLine("===========================");
        return;
    }

    int total_eggs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chickens; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write("Eggs:");
        int eggs = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out eggs))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of eggs:");
        }
        total_eggs += eggs;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(Message(total_eggs));
}
```